# How to create this list more elegantly

Tags: list-manipulation

There is list containing some $(i,j)$ values of indices. Now i want to create a 
matrix of dimension n $\times$ m whose entries are 1 for the indices corresponding
to the given list otherwise its zero.

For e.g if the list is as given below

```
list = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 3}};
```

And if $n=m=3$ then the output should be

```
 {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}
```

I was able to do this as shown below but i believe this could be
achieved with a shorter and a more elegant code. Maybe a one liner.

```
      cHeck[n1_, n2_] := Module[{flag = 0, list, i},
                         list = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 3}};
                         For[i = 1, i <= Length[list], i++,
                           Which[{n1, n2} === list[[i]], flag = 1]
                             ];
                        flag
                            ]
 A[n_, m_] := Table[cHeck[i, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, m}]

 A[3, 3] 
 (*{{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}*)
```

Comment: Try `SparseArray[# -> 1 & /@ list, {n, m}, 0]`.

Comment: wow that worked. i knew there would be a one liner. Thanks.

Comment: @rm-rf I disagree with closing this question as a duplicate of the one you chose.  That one is considerably more complex and obscures the simplicity if what is needed here.  I searched for a duplicate myself and found many examples with `Band`, as well as many uses of `SparseArray` as part of a larger answer, but I did not fine one that I felt was a duplicate.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Isn't the solution the same as your `f1`? Just with `list -> 1` instead of individually setting them? Feel free to reopen it if you feel it isn't addressed by the other one.

Comment: @rm-rf The syntax is different; the answers to this question show that both `ReplacePart` and `SparseArray` can accept the form `positionlist -> value` without the need for mapping or threading.  The first comment above shows that people are not all aware of this.  Closer are some of the answers I found using `Band`.  I am going to reopen this for now; if you come across another Q&A that is not overly involved that clearly shows the syntax I describe please close it again.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SparseArray.html):

```
list = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 3}};

n = m = 3;

SparseArray[list -> 1, {n, m}] // MatrixForm
```

> ```
> 1 1 0
> 1 0 0
> 0 0 1
> ```

Timing compared to `ReplacePart` as proposed by bill s:

```
list = DeleteDuplicates @ RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, {75000, 2}];
n = m = 1000;

ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, {n, m}], list -> 1] // AbsoluteTiming // First
SparseArray[list -> 1, {n, m}]                   // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.170
>
> 0.018
> ```

The `SparseArray` object can be converted to a standard array using [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Normal.html) in negligible time.

Answer (score 4):

If the matrix is already defined, you can use ReplacePart:

```
list = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 3}};
q = ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}];

ReplacePart[q, list -> 1]
{{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}
```

Of course, this is more lines than the `SparseArray` solution.

Comment: This is faster than I remembered it being. +1.  However it's still not nearly as fast as `SparseArray`, at least in v7.

Answer (score 0):

Also: `MapAt`

```
list = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 3}};
q = ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}];

MapAt[1 &, q, list]
```

> {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}

Note: this is much slower than both `SparseArray` and `ReplacePart`.